# Is it possible to send some data on connect to the server in socket.io?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I want to send the username on connection (the moment we connect) to the server, something like this :

```
const socketConnect=io("http://localhost:3000","myusername")
```

Is something like this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. See the client API documentation [here](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/#iourl).

What you have to listen to is the connect event and then send your username:

```
const socket=io("http://localhost:3000")
socket.on("connect", () => {
    socket.emit("login", userData, (serverReply) => {
      console.log("Server's response", serverReply);
    });
    // ...
});
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 4):

This is possible using the query option on the client side per the [Client API documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/#iourl).

**Client**

```
const socketConnect = io('http://localhost:3000', {
  query: { 'myusername_key': 'myusername_value' },
});
```

**Server**

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  const myusername = socket.handshake.query.myusername_key;
  // do whatever
});
```